# Programmatically format the java code using java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I would like to format strings which contains codes like:

```
 "function() { for(i=0;i<n;i++){ return i; }}"
```

The point is to put new lines to each ; except in the for loop, so the formatted output should be something like this:

```
function() {
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    return i;
  } 
 }
```

Is there any written function for this, or I have to loop through the whole string?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: IDE eclipse > format ? Also, you are also adding a new line after `{` and `}` in your sample... Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `google-java-format-1.5.jar` and `google-java-format-1.5-all-deps.jar`

and see the below example code

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
      try {
        System.out.println(formatter.formatSource("public class Test{public static void main(String[] args) {String s;}}"));
      } catch (FormatterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

and output will be

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s;
  }
}
```

Sample working code
[image: Sample]

Hope this would helps to you

Comment: Don't post links only, an answer should include an explanation and the interesting content. See [answer]

Comment: added the example please check it

Comment: Better but... Don't post your code in an image. Copy paste it using the { } button. It allow search engine to use the text to be referenced.

Comment: How can I implement this to android, using android studio?

Comment: Same way as how you are importing/linking jar